# How is certain area of waveguide becomes visible to user?

Tags: optics, fiber-optics, waveguide

I was reading an article and came across this image
[image]
As shown, image becomes visible
to eye after reaching a specific area of the glass. But how does it work? Why is it being reflected at such a weird angle?

Comment: Looks like there are striations on the light pipe surface, scattering light out of the pipe. The image does not appear to be a physics-based one.

Comment: And I specifically used ‘light pipe’ rather than waveguide.

Comment: I asked about the last part of the glass, where it becomes visible to eye, not the reflecting part. I took this photo from here: https://uploadvr.com/waveguides-smartglasses/